# External USB 3.0 HDD makes loud click sound while shutting down

Tags: hard-drive

Am using a Dell Inspiron N4110 14" laptop with OCZ 60GB SSD as boot/internal HDD. I use an HGST Touro 1TB external HDD for my storage needs (on a USB 3.0 port). The system is running on dual-boot configuration with Windows 7 Ultimate & Ubuntu 14.04 (both fresh installation). Since couple of days am noticing a loud click from the external drive every time I shut down the laptop from Ubuntu. I can confirm that, this is NOT happening when I shut down from Windows (external drive powers off smoothly without making any audible noise). Any thoughts, why this is happening in Ubuntu but NOT in Windows? Do let me know if I need to provide any system logs.